# What happened to Thorn Tree?

Tags: discussion

Maybe it's not cricket to ask about one travel forum on another forum, but someone has to know.  Why is [Thorn Tree](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/) shut down?  The message is very mysterious.  Is there a scandal?

Comment: There was some chat about it in [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7397926#7397926)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Sydney Morning Herald (and associated papers) have published details of apparently what happened to cause the shutdown - http://www.smh.com.au/technology/technology-news/lonely-planet-shuts-thorn-tree-forum-over-paedophilia-posts-20121226-2bvtd.html

Comment: SMH's version of the story is "strongly denied" by the BBC, although they're unhelpfully refusing to provide their own version. http://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/bbc-shuts-down-thorn-tree-travel-forum-on-lonely-planet-website-over-uncomfortable-themes-8431501.html

Comment: Appears to be back now!